# Using x-amazon-apigateway-integration to return a query parameter in the body with `Content-Type text/plain`

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

We're trying to set up an API gateway that accepts a `POST` request with a `?validationToken={token}` query parameter, and responds to that `POST` with a body containing **only** `token` with a `Content-Type text/plain` header.

We're doing this in Terraform (using Terragrunt) and have something like this (sensitive parts omitted):

```json
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
  "httpMethod" : "POST",
  "responses" : {
    "default" : {
      "statusCode" : "200",
      "responseTemplates" : {
        "text/plain" : "$input.params('validationToken')"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

This somewhat works, in that if you make a `POST` with `?validationToken={token}` the response body will be `token`.

The problem is that it always has a `Content-Type application/json`. Is there a way to control this header in the `reponseTemplates`?

I tried to add this inside of `default`:

```json
"responseParameters" : {
   "method.response.header.Content-Type" : "'text/plain'"
}
```

... but it gives an error of `Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.Content-Type`

What mostly confuses me here is that I'm using `responseTemplates.['text/plain']` to send back the token in the body, but the content type isn't being set on the response?